# Spring application failing to start with the exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: SpringAnnotPckg.JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm a beginner in Spring. I have created a configuration and added component scanning in that class and trying to create spring context, it is throwing the below exception. Please help me.

Configuration class

```
package SpringAnnotPckg;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("SpringAnnotPckg")
public class JavaConfig {
    public JavaConfig() {
        
    }
}
```

main class

```
package SpringAnnotPckg;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
public class TestJavaconfig {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context=new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JavaConfig.class);
Car car=context.getBean("audiCar",Car.class);
car.print();
context.close();
    }
}
```

Exception

```
Jul 06, 2022 1:19:01 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3fd7a715: startup date [Wed Jul 06 13:19:01 IST 2022]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: SpringAnnotPckg.JavaConfig
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:403)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:249)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:281)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at SpringAnnotPckg.TestJavaconfig.main(TestJavaconfig.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:110)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:393)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @641147d0
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @641147d0
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You can try importing the `JavaConfig.class` to the main class.
Or try declaring the main class as `TestJavaconfig extends JavaConfig` or `TestJavaconfig implements JavaConfig`.
I'm new to Spring as well so let me know if any of it works as it will help me too.